# I am not able to call on any python commands in Python 64bit (Python installing elsewhere despite setting installation path)

Tags: python

Python 64 bit is not allowing me to call upon any commands, CMD is. I check APP DATA folder and low n behold despite setting installation path to C/Program Files, it's installing to APP DATA. I have been searching for the past 2 weeks how to take care of this issue and start to learn how to code so I can scrape images from imgur search resuts.... Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

[image: img]

[image: img]

https://python-forum.io/Thread-More-than-a-couple-problems

Comment: Please post your code and output as text. Screenshots of code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: you already installed it in your first screen shot ... pip only works from the command line ... inside python just do `import PIL`  (I think it still imports like this ... if not `import pillow`

Comment: I doubt it was for no reason. Regardless, see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: python is an interpreter and cannot run terminal commands. This is not even a question friend because you cannot run a cmd command on python interpreter and say that its not working. and i agree with @JoranBeasley

Comment: Worth pointing out that Pillow is for _processing images_, not downloading from websites. And IMGUR has a (deprecated) API library - https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython

Answer (score 1):

Installation path isn't an issue, and really shouldn't be something that you should worry about (unless you have strict policies in a cooporation and don't have admin permissions to certain file locations)

It also **did** install into program files

[image]

1. `chrome` is not a Windows command, as it says. `pillow` was successfully installed along with other stuff
2. You cannot run `pip` from inside a Python REPL session

You should instead `import pillow` and continue on, as you wish, however I would suggest using Pycharm or Spyder rather than a terminal window

> Downloading pycharm was a huge mistake cause it messes file locations up further

It actually doesn't...

Comment: I cannot delete questions. You can.